# Rmarkdown table gets corrupted when knitted to Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating a package in Rstudio and want to include a table in the README.md file, on github. The README.md file is knitted from a README.rmd file.

It works fine, but when I insert a Rmd table, it gets corrupted in the md format:

In README.rmd, I include:

```
Table Header  | Second Header
------------- | -------------
Table Cell | Cell 2
Cell 3 | Cell 4
```

After `knitr`, this becomes:

```
Table Header | Second Header ------------- | ------------- Table Cell | Cell 2 Cell 3 | Cell 4
```

which does not get rendered as an HTML table.

Is there a way to pass a nicely formatted table from Rmd to md?

OBS: editing the Markdown directly to fix the table is not a viable option because Rstudio version control (git) will impose that the .md file can not be ahead of the .Rmd file.

Edit 1: aligned the | in header and 2nd line (see above). That did not solve it. Aligning the rest of the table also does not solve this.

Edit 2: I cross posted as an [issue #1222](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1222) at the knitr github page.

Comment: I would recommend using [printr](https://github.com/yihui/printr). It takes care of converting regular R output into nice tables in .md files and ultimately .html files.

Comment: This works! Tks. Please post that as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Use results='asis'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [printr](https://github.com/yihui/printr) package. It converts regular R output into nice-looking tables in the Knitr context.

Comment: https://github.com/yihui/printr, You will need to install devtools and use the following line to install `devtools::install_git("https://github.com/yihui/printr")`

Comment: although the printr solution works, knitr should be able to convert the tables to md on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aligning the header with the dashed line so that the `|` are aligned?

```
Table Header | Second Header
------------ | -------------
Table Cell | Cell 2
Cell 3 | Cell 4
```

Comment: tks. I just tried. See edit above. Did not solve it.